# Custom action bar show dark padding left after upgrade project to Android SDK version 21

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-support-library

I have just upgraded my project to Android SDK version 21 today. I increase the version of android support appcompat v7 to 21.0.0. I was through that everything will be ok, and it should be ok. But after all of that, the action bar start show a dark padding on the left.

I am using custom action bar (DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM)

Screenshots are bellow:

Before: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfNuX.jpg

After: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pL1vw.jpg

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: code code code where is the code : even doctor needs to see patient to diagnose :p

Answer (score 6):

After a few weeks now I finally figured it out! You need to create a custom ActionBar Theme setting Left and Right Inset to **0dp** like this:

```
<style name="CustomLightTheme.ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
    <item name="contentInsetLeft">0dp</item>
</style>
```

and then use the theme like this:

```
<item name="actionBarStyle">@style/CustomLightTheme.ActionBar</item>
```